# How can I create a static variable in a Python class via the C API?

Tags: python, c

I want to do the equivalent of

```
class Foo(object):
  bar = 1
```

using Python's C API. In other words, I want to create a Python class which has a static variable, using C.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it! It's just a matter of setting the tp_dict element of the type object and filling adding entries to it for each of the static variables. The following C code creates the same static variable as the Python code above:

```
PyTypeObject type;
// ...other initialisation...
type.tp_dict = PyDict_New();
PyDict_SetItemString(type.tp_dict, "bar", PyInt_FromLong(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass that source code to [Py_CompileString](http://docs.python.org/c-api/veryhigh.html#Py_CompileString) with the appropriate flags.

If you already have the class you could use [PyObject_SetAttr](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html#PyObject_SetAttr).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It seems a bit of a roundabout way to do it though - is there anything similar to PyModule_AddIntConstant for classes?

Comment: Sorry, I only just noticed that you updated your answer. Thanks again for the help.

I've tried using PyObject_SetAttr, but no matter when I call it I get a TypeError with the message "can't set attributes of built-in/extension type X" (where X is my type name). Am I doing something wrong, or does this simply not work with type objects?

Comment: I found the solution I was after in the end. Thanks a lot for your suggestions though!